# Fail2Ban RegEx works but filter does not

Tags: apache2, regex, fail2ban

my plan is to ban all accesses to my webserver which repeatedly produce 404-errors and obviously do some scanning only

For this I tried

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/otheraccess.log '^<HOST>. - - .* "(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 404 .*$'
```

which reported me to have several hundred of matches. But when I add this regular expression to my fail2ban-filter

```
failregex = ^<HOST>.* - - .* "(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*" 404 .*$
ignoreregex =.*(robots.txt|favicon.ico|jpg|png|sitemap|sitemap.txt|sitemap.xml.gz|sitemap_index.xml) to my filter, fail2.ban
```

it finds nothing:

```
# fail2ban-client status apache-404
Status for the jail: apache-404
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     0
|  `- File list:        /var/log/apache2/access.log /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned:     0
   `- Banned IP list:
```

So...any idea what the reason could be/where to look at why the rule is ignored within fail2ban?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a sample set of lines that fail2ban is shipped to be parsing. Make sure some should match but some should not. Also include your fail2ban configuration section from `jail.local` for the Apache logging. Also double check the `ignoreregex` line as it looks like you've got a typo somewhere

Comment: How does your jail for apache-404 look like?https://bobcares.com/blog/fail2ban-apache-404/

Comment: @Turdie the configuration in this tutorial is complete crap - when I do a "fail2ban-client reload" with that, fail2ban never comes back

Comment: Then there something wrong on your side because that's a valid command

Answer (score 0):

Let's start over and please remove all the configurations you made

---

Can you please please make a filter in filter.d like this

```
failregex = ^.*&quot;(GET|POST|HEAD).*&quot; (404|444|403|400) .*$
ignoreregex =
```

---

```
prevent-apache-404.conf in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d
```

---

Then create a jail in /etc/fail2ban/jaild.d/apache404.conf

```
[prevent-apache-404]
enabled   = true
port      = http,https
filter    = prevent-apache-404
logpath   = /var/log/apache*/*access.log
findtime  = 600
maxretry  = 4
```

---

Then restart fail2ban and check the status

```
sudo service fail2ban stop
sudo service fail2ban start
sudo service fail2ban status
sudo fail2ban-client status
sudo fail2ban-client status prevent-apache-404
```

---

Note:The most recent Debian (bookworm) distribution made systemd-journald logging the default, so make sure rsyslog is logging.